# Spring security runs into" Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded. "

Tags: java, spring-security

I am using session management in spring security to limit number of concurrent users per username.

Although it perfectly works but after few minutes of using the application without logging out, it redirects to index page and does not allow the same user to log-in again. To log-in again I need to re-run the application.

```
  <session-management invalid-session-url="/index">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </session-management> 
    <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
```

After adding the following to web.xml also it runs into following error

**web.xml**

```
    <listener>
<listener-
     class>org.springframework.security.ui.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**Error**

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.springframework.security.ui.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong classname (it's from an outdated version of Spring Security). Your `web.xml` should contain

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>
     org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

This is covered in [the namespace chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-session-mgmt) of the manual, and also in the chapter on [session management](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#concurrent-sessions).

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html)

If you use this mechanism to detect session timeouts, it may falsely report an error if the user logs out and then logs back in without closing the browser. This is because the session cookie is not cleared when you invalidate the session and will be resubmitted even if the user has logged out. You may be able to explicitly delete the JSESSIONID cookie on logging out, for example by using the following syntax in the logout handler:

```
  <http>
    <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
  </http>
```

web.xml

```
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.security.ui.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Unfortunately this can't be guaranteed to work with every servlet container, so you will need to test it in your environment

Comment: Did not help still runs into same issue

Comment: ran into following error SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.springframework.security.ui.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher