# Spring security does not allow me to re-login t oaccounts that were logged out

Tags: cookies, spring-security, session-cookies

I can easily log in any user into my application, but once I log out I can not log in with the same user again. 
So I need to re-run the application to be able to log in with that account.

When I try to log-in for the second time it shows the following message which is supposed to be shown against concurrent accesses.

```
Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded.
```

**Logout**

```
  <a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />" > Logout</a>
```

**myproject-security.xml**

```
       <session-management invalid-session-url="/index">
          <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
       </session-management>
       <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,User,UserID"/>
 </http>
```

Comment: Sounds like a [duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009028/spring-security-runs-into-maximum-sessions-of-1-for-this-principal-exceeded).

Comment: @LukeTaylor I tried that but did not help, if I close the browser without logging out I need to log in again and after log in it shows the error.

Comment: That is normal behaviour. In your question you said you logged out, which means actively clicking a logout link and thus destroying the session. If you don't log out, the user still has an active session on the server. You have set `error-if-maximum-exceeded=true`, so you get an error.

Comment: @LukeTaylor as I explained once I log out I can not log in again; However, as far as I know, the normal behavior is to be able to log in to system after each log out. The maximum-exceeded parameter is set to avoid concurrent login not a user who has already logged out of system and wants to log in again.

Comment: Sorry, but in your comment above you said "if I close the browser without logging out", so it isn't clear from your question that you are actually logging out of the application. Check that the session is being invalidated and removed from the `SessionRegistry`. You should see corresponding output in the debug log.

Comment: can you add the full configuration of the http element (and  for which spring security this is)?

Comment: @jhadesdev what do you mean by http element?

Comment: I meant the content of <http></http>, but any spring-security related config would in general help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included the following codes into my web.xml

```
  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
    </listener>
   <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
```